# How to access a bookmarked query in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I bookmarked a MySQL query in phpMyAdmin.  How do I access it? I looked all over PhpMyAdmin but could not locate it.

Answer (score 15):

To run the bookmarked query, select the database your query is for (usually in the left-hand column in phpMyAdmin). Then go to "SQL" at the top of the screen. You should then see a section on the page called "Bookmarked SQL query" with a drop-down selector for any bookmarked SQL queries you have.

[image: phpMyAdmin bookmarked queries]

I run into the problem that phpMyAdmin seems to duplicate my bookmarked SQL queries when I edit them, and then both the old and new queries are stored with the same bookmark name. To find out what the query SQL actually is, you need to do the following:

- View the source of the list of bookmarked queries in the drop-down SQL. The IDs of each bookmark are stored in the HTML, e.g.:

> ```
> <option value="123">Bookmark_name_1</option>
> <option value="72">Bookmark_name_2</option>
> ```

- In phpMyAdmin, go to "SQL" and paste in the following SQL query:

> ```
> SELECT
> id, label, CONVERT( query USING utf8 ) as query 
> FROM pma_bookmark
> WHERE id IN ( 72, 123 );
> ```

- When you hit "Go" you should see the queries in plain text.
- You can then go to the pma_bookmark table in the phpmyadmin database and delete the query with the ID you don't want.

Answer (score 8):

My phpMyAdmin Version is 4.5.2 and I'm to new to be allowed to add images to a post so I will try to describe how to get to the saved bookmarks the best I can.

- On the main page after you have logged in Click on one of the database names in the left column.
- When the database structure view comes up there is a small icon at the bottom left of that view. You might have to scroll down to see it and it looks like a small command prompt window with the word Console next to it. Click on that and if it is too narrow to see anything you can drag it upward to make it larger.
- You may only see the title bar with clickable tabs click on the Bookmarks one and if you have saved Bookmarks they will be visible in the box below.
- Then as your mouse passes over the Bookmarked sqls a clickable bar appears over the sql or query with choices "Expand", "Requery", "Edit" and "Delete".

Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the SQL History feature like this:

[image]

Comment: I think he`s asking about phpmyadmin,not php.

Comment: @Mihai:- Updating my answer. I went with the tag!

Answer (score 1):

For that go to php myadmin and click on sql tab. in that window there is option like get auto-saved query. click on it. you will get your saved query back. now click on Go button and execute it.

above option is use when you saved your query without provide name. and if you have bookmarked your query with name then use below option.

Go to SQL tab and there is bookmarked query option. Click any bookmarked query from dropdown menu and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

## 05 2022

xampp: `3.3.0`
phpMyAdmin: `10.4.21`

If anyone still looking for a clear explanation, then here it is.
Assuming you have already bookmarked your query

1. Select your database
2. Go to the 'SQL' tab and scroll down
3. You should be able to see a section called 'Bookmarked SQL query'. **You will only see this section if you have already bookmarked any query from THIS database**.
4. Use the dropdown to select your query.

[image]

### Something to keep in mind

1. The query is tied to your database. If you select another database and you will see this 'Bookmarked SQL query' section.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

first, you need to generate a bookmark query list after that you can see the bookmark query list.

if you check the bookmark query then follow  below mentioned step

1. Generate a bookmark list.
2. after that go to the SQL section and then see the option of  "Bookmarked SQL Query" option.
3. in this dropdown whatever write a query name to select after you can View the query OR Run the Query as well as delete a query
4. after clicking on the Go button

**NOTE** If you select a radio button then work meanwhile